# Gmail: check emails from other email accounts without importing old emails

Tags: email, gmail, email-client, gmail-imap

it's possible to use Gmail to check emails from other work email accounts without importing all old emails from 10 years ago?

Comment: Hi @Mike can you provide additional information regarding the other accounts.  For example are any of them Gmail or Google Workspace backed accounts?  How do you access them? POP? IMAP?  When you say use 'Gmail' what do you mean?  Browser based Gmail?  Gmail on your PC?  On your mobile device (IOS/Andriod)? etc.